# Sharepoint - Using ScriptLink with js in Library

Tags: sharepoint-2010

How can i include js which is in a sharepoint library. I tried that but without succes:

```
<SharePoint:ScriptLink ID="Formjs"   runat="server" Localizable="false"  Name="<% $SPUrl:~SiteCollection/My Library/myjs.js %>" />
```

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

I just did this, I have my js in a doclib called "scripts", so its just

```
<script src="/scripts/myfile.js" language="javascript"></script>
```

That did it for me because I didn't need any of the advanced scriptlink options.